# Cannot activate bools or deactivate them in a while loop C#

Tags: c#, boolean

I'm working through a problem on Codeeasy.net and I cannot for the life of me figure it out. If someone could help me. This is what it is supposed to do.

```
class AntivirusScan
{
    static void Main(string[] args)         
    {
        int fileIndex     = 0;
        bool hideMode     = false;
        bool heDoesntKnow = true;

        while (heDoesntKnow)
        {
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (answer == "scan")
            {
                fileIndex = fileIndex + 1;
                Console.WriteLine($"scanning file {fileIndex}");
            }

            if (hideMode == true)
                 Console.WriteLine($"can't scan files for viruses");
            if (answer == "hide")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"can't scan files for viruses");
                hideMode = true;
            }
            if (answer == "unhide")
            {
                fileIndex=fileIndex+1;
                Console.WriteLine($"scanning file {fileIndex}");
                hideMode=false;
            }

            if (answer == "game over")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"run");
                heDoesntKnow = false;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

This is my code. It is supposed to return that it can't scan if it is hidden. Instead it just powers through it. It shows up once and then continues to not do what it is supposed to.

It is supposed to read from the prompt which is

```
scan
scan
hide
scan
scan
unhide
scan
game over
```

This is what it outputs

```
scanning file 1
scanning file 2
can't scan files for viruses

scanning file 3
can't scan files for viruses

scanning file 4
can't scan files for viruses
can't scan files for viruses

scanning file 5
scanning file 6
run
```

This is what it is supposed to output

```
scanning file 1
scanning file 2
can't scan files for viruses
can't scan files for viruses
scanning file 3
run
```

Comment: Is it because you want `continue;` somewhere, or `else if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your check for hide is after, **instead of within**, the if statement for scanning. I have also made your code a little more readable and simplified a couple of statements.

```
using System;

namespace WhileLoop
{
    class AntivirusScan
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
           int fileIndex = 0;
           bool hideMode = false;
           bool heDoesntKnow = true;

           while (heDoesntKnow)
            {
                     string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                     if (answer == "scan") {
                        if (hideMode) {
                            Console.WriteLine($"can't scan files for viruses");
                         } else {
                            fileIndex++;
                            Console.WriteLine($"scanning file {fileIndex}");
                         }
                     }

                     if(answer == "hide")
                     {
                        Console.WriteLine($"can't scan files for viruses");
                        hideMode=true;
                     }

                     if (answer == "unhide")
                     {
                        fileIndex=fileIndex+1;
                        Console.WriteLine($"scanning file {fileIndex}");
                        hideMode=false;
                     }

                     if (answer == "game over")
                     {
                        Console.WriteLine($"run");
                        heDoesntKnow = false;
                     }
          }
     }
 }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked beautifully. I was not sure how to implement this (the site doesn't really explain that well and throws it at you, but that's the fun of it! :D ). But thank you so very much again for taking the time to show me how it's done. Simple and I would never have thought of it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

From your expected output i guess the inputs are

> 1)scan 
>   2)scan 
>   3)hide 
>     4)scan 
>     5)unhide
>     6)game over

So as per your code i think you have to add one more constraint on the first if condition :

```
 if (answer == "scan")
 {
   fileIndex=fileIndex+1;
   Console.WriteLine($"scanning file {fileIndex}");
  }
```

This should be changed to

```
if (answer == "scan" && !hideMode)
 {
   fileIndex=fileIndex+1;
   Console.WriteLine($"scanning file {fileIndex}");
 }
```

so that this if block doesn't get executed when hideMode is true. And move your if(answer == 'hide'){} block to be after scan check.

Final code :

using System;

```
namespace WhileLoop
{
    class AntivirusScan
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
int fileIndex = 0;
bool hideMode = false;
bool heDoesntKnow = true;

          while (heDoesntKnow)
            {
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (answer == "scan" && !hideMode)
                {
                    fileIndex = fileIndex + 1;
                    Console.WriteLine($"scanning file {fileIndex}");
                }

                if (answer == "unhide")
                {
                    fileIndex = fileIndex + 1;
                    Console.WriteLine($"scanning file {fileIndex}");
                    hideMode = false;
                }

                if (hideMode == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"can't scan files for viruses");
                }
                if (answer == "hide")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"can't scan files for viruses");
                    hideMode = true;
                }


                if (answer == "game over")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("run");
                    heDoesntKnow = false;
                }
            }
     }
 }}
```

Hope this helps :)